# Server/Database for Android App

Tags: android, database

I am looking to develop an Android app that interfaces with a server backend (hosting a database and functionality). I am just trying out an idea for the app, so don't want to spend anything on buying the server but my requirements for memory space and user footprint is very less.

I have explored options like setting up my own box with an external facing IP, but that is not an option for me given the time constraints.

What are the best providers available that will give me what I need for free? I plan to upgrade to a paid server with greater memory and user footprint once my idea gets launched.

Answer (score 0):

There are several free options available, depending on your use cases. Take a look at [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances, or [Google's Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine/).

You could also host a [SQLite instance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) within the phone itself, if your data is static.